# n2cms Admin errors when the content item is clicked in managemen UIt

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, n2cms

I am using N2CMS in my project. I have two project in the solution 
1. N2CMS Controllers, Views and Models
2. N2CMS Management UI Zip

I am using N2CMS Admin to manage Content Model defined in my first project. The Management UI is able to load all the Models defined in the first Project. But the Management UI is unable to show the view.

It says

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: You may find some help here http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/239101

Comment: Does it work if you install all of the components into the same project? What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? What version of N2CMS? Did you install it via the Nuget packages?